# put Blank in INTEGER Datatype oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

I have to put blank i.e '' into a column of INTEGER Data type.
I do not have to put NULL into it. The requirement is to put blank ''.

Comment: An empty string is an invalid number. If you don't have a value for your number the **only** sensible way to store that is to put `NULL` into that column. That's what `NULL` is for. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: It is showing NULL on printing

Comment: Then you should change your printing routine, rather than messing up your data model

Comment: I cannot change it as printing is done on client end. Thanks anyways. I will use 0.

Comment: In Oracle you can not store an empty string `''`. It will be stored as `NULL` in a varchar column.

Comment: In VARCHAR2 you can store '' '

Comment: No you can not. Not in Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF30037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, you can not since it's `INTEGER` datatype. Either it will have numbers (0,1,2,...,n) or `NULL`. If you want to store string literal then choose a string datatype like `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Oracle does not store empty strings. An empty string `''` is stored as `NULL` in Oracle. Plus: recommending to store numbers in `varchar` columns is not a good idea.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, perhaps your interpretation is wrong. I am not recommending to store numbers in varchar columns rather recommending to store string type in varchar column if that's what OP's intent.